# Unable to install composer globally on Cygwin

Tags: php, json, xampp, composer-php, phar

When I run the this command 'php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php' on Cygwin terminal. The following errors have been triggered on the terminal:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json

The phar extension is missing. 
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

The iconv OR mbstring extension is required and both are missing.
Install either of them or recompile php without --disable-iconv
```

However, all these extensions are enabled in php.ini file. I am using XAMPP.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to install the correct php extensions ...

```
apt-cyg install \
php \
php-json \
php-phar \
php-mysql \
php-curl \
php-gd \
php-intl \
php-imap \
php-mcrypt \
php-pspell \
php-recode \
php-tidy \
php-xmlrpc \
php-xsl
```

PS: I created a install-script for this :) https://github.com/voku/dotfiles/blob/master/firstInstallCygwin.sh

Comment: Brilliant.. didn't know you there was apt flavour for Cygwin.. and how you just put it there and remove it when done.. wow. Plus you actually found a use for Lynx!